# Character encoding problem?

Tags: php, android, character-encoding

I was testing a webpage that I designed on my Android 2.1 browser but it complains with the following:

> error on line 1 at Column 39: Unsupported encoding ISO8859-1

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: `ISO8859-1` => `ISO-8859-1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

and/or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```